# tikz center and fit the text into a Node

Tags: tikz-node

I have been having difficulties to make nodes fit the text in tikz.

What I have done so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, chains, fit, quotes,positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm,
  start chain = A going right,
   txt/.style = {text height=2pt, text depth=2.pt,
                 on chain},
every edge/.append style = {draw, -stealth'}
                        ]

\node [txt] {\phantom{ this is text }};    


\node (f1)  [ fill=blue!20,inner ysep=2.pt, 
        inner xsep=2pt, 
        anchor=text, 
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners=1mm,
             fit=(A-1) (A-1)] {{ This is text}};



    \end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

, which results in
[image]

Whereas the desired output should look like:
[image]
, which not only centers the text but also fits the node to the text (i.e. not using a lot of unneeded space).

Any thoughts

Comment: You use `fit=(A-1) (A-1)` in example, and it enlarges the node `(f1)`. Can you explain where does node `(A-1)` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{stix2} % use STIX2 font 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [fill=blue!20, inner sep=3pt, rounded corners=1mm] 
    {This is text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer though when I apply your solution to mine I still cannot get the text centered.